# Show External Image in RDLC Tablix based on ID Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010, dynamic-rdlc-generation

It been one day hole to shortout this.

I have created a tablix with column like this :

- StuID    ----------      -StuName---------Image(External)
- P1-      -------------------A   -----------     show image of stuID
- P2  --------- ---------     B  ------------- show image of stuID

StuID & StuName - Comes From SQL server 2008 table

Image - Comes from file:\MY-pc\pic\

All the Image comes from my PC folder like this value :

> =IIF("file:\MY-pc\pic\" & ("P" & Fields!stuID.Value.ToString) & ".PNG" Is Nothing,
>   "file:\MY-pc\pic\NoPhoto.PNG",
>   "file:\MY-pc\pic\P" & Fields!stuID.Value & ".PNG")

All Images showing but if their is no Image based on stuID its not showing NoPhoto.PNG.

Is there any solution from your side.

Comment: no one here to help me????????????????

Comment: ???????????????????????????????????//

Comment: Waiting 4 ur Response..............("_")